# When trying to deploy solution, facing 'Remote SharePoint site connection not support' error occurred. How to fix this?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

When trying to deploy solution,  facing 'Remote SharePoint site connection not support' error occurred. How to fix this?

> "Error :  Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application
>   Pool': Remote SharePoint site connections are not supported.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that Visual Studio thinks your local site collection is remote,

the solution is to

- Edit your `HOSTS` file at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc`
- Place your site collections (sharepoint@asds.com) in there pointing at 127.0.0.1 (your machine ID).
- Save and close , Try again.

[image]

Ref : [Remote SharePoint Site Connections Not Supported](https://platinumdogs.me/2014/01/14/remote-sharepoint-site-connections-not-supported-using-visual-studio-2013-and-host-named-site-collections/)

Answer (score 5):

I think given site URL for your project is not your local site collection's URL. You can change it from below steps.

1. Go to Visual Studio
2. Select Project (not solution)
3. Press F4
4. You will Site URL
5. Give your local site collection's URL here

Comment: This solved the problem for me, after I had already added hosts entries without any luck.

Comment: Short and right answer. It works in one go.